# Cambios de color con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy aprendiendo **JavaScript** y tengo problema con el siguiente ejercicio
dentro de mi `html` tengo mis `ID` el cual tienen el nombre de colores rojo y azul.

y dentro de mi **JS** tengo mi siguiente línea de código.

```
const redButton = document.getElementById('redButton');
const blueButton = document.getElementById('blueButton');

redButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const colorSquare = document.getElementById('colorDiv');
  colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});

blueButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
})
```

Lo que quiero es que al momento de hacer *click* en el botón *red*, el `ID` `colorDiv` cambie de color a rojo y cuando se haga *click* en el botón azul cambie el color a azul.

Yo creo que la forma para esto es con condicionales `if` y `else`, pero no se como declararlo para que se efectúe este evento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No podías visualizar los cambios por que tu `div` no tenía tamaño alguno.

Código:

```js
const redButton = document.getElementById('redButton');
const blueButton = document.getElementById('blueButton');
const colorSquare = document.getElementById('colorDiv');
redButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
blueButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
```

```css
#colorDiv{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="redButton">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" id="blueButton">Click Me!</button>
<div id="colorDiv"></div>
```

Ahora sobre tu duda:

> ¿Esto también se podría haber solucionado con condicionales `if` y `else`?

Nótese que en este ejemplo se necesita de una variable para poder cumplir con las condiciones de `if` y `else`.

Para probar el ejemplo, debes modificar el valor de la variable `n`, y recién verás cambios de colores.

```js
var n = 30;//cambia el valor y veras cambios en el color del div

if (n >= 60)
{
    document.getElementById("miDiv").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
else  
if (n >= 41 && n <50)  
{
    document.getElementById("miDiv").style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}  
else  
if (n <=40)  
{
    document.getElementById("miDiv").style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

```css
#miDiv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="miDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió de mucho, solo quisiera comentare esto también se podría haber solucionado con condicionales if y else ?

Comment: @PoloMoreno la logica para este tipo de efectos es distinta a programacion a objetos, ya que se trata de eventos de usuario, talves se podria hacer, pero no seria la manera mas adecuada.

Comment: @PoloMoreno espera te muestro con otro ejemplo como seria con if else, te servira para diferenciar la logica

Comment: @PoloMoreno te deje otro ejemplo en una nueva respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como muy bien te ha comentado @x-rw, lo que le falta a tu código para que se vea el cambio de color de fondo de tu `div` es asignarle un tamaño.

Sin embargo, me gustaría darte una **recomendación:** no cambies los estilos directamente con el atributo `style` de Javascript, si no que usa clases en su defecto, las cuales también puedes cambiar desde Javascript.

**¿Por qué no hacerlo con el atributo style?**

Porque si tu utilizas:

```
colorSquare.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

lo que estás haciendo en realidad es esto:

```
<div id="colorDiv" style="background-color: blue"></div>
```

Según la **[especificidad de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)**, *los estilos inline añadidos a un elemento (p.e., style="font-weight:bold") siempre sustituyen a cualquier estilo escrito en hojas de estilo externas*, o lo que es lo mismo, si tienes una clase o un ID sobreescribiendo este estilo, no vas a poder, ya que los estilos inline son los que tienen una mayor especificidad.

Por lo tanto, te recomiendo usar clases en su defecto y cambiarlas mediante Javascript.

- Para añadir una clase a un elemento:

  ```
  colorSquare.classList.add("rojo");
  ```
- Para quitar una clase a un elemento:

  ```
  colorSquare.classList.remove("rojo");
  ```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
const redButton = document.getElementById('redButton');
const blueButton = document.getElementById('blueButton');
const colorSquare = document.getElementById('colorDiv');
redButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    colorSquare.classList.remove("azul");
    colorSquare.classList.add("rojo");
});
blueButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    colorSquare.classList.remove("rojo");
    colorSquare.classList.add("azul");
});
```

```css
#colorDiv{
   width:10px;
   height:10px;
}

.azul{
   background-color: blue;
}

.rojo{
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="redButton">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" id="blueButton">Click Me!</button>
<div id="colorDiv"></div>
```